# How to adjust the tempo when playing a MIDI file with MIDI.js?

Tags: javascript, midi

I'm using [MIDI.js](https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js) to play a MIDI file. I'd like to adjust the tempo on the fly, based on user input. Is there a way to eg. inject `setTempo` events to the MIDI stream?

Also, I'd probably like to ignore any `setTempo` events in the MIDI file itself.

Do I need to fork the player code to achieve these?

Comment: Where are you getting `setTempo`? Can't find it in any of the js files.

Comment: @remyabel: it's mentioned [a few times in the source](https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/search?q=setTempo&ref=cmdform).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set something like `MIDI.Player.BPM = 60;` somewhere before loading midi file. Found in [the source](https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=BPM&type=Code).

So, this probably means that you can not change BPM during file playback.